# How to stop Visual Studio Code from endlessly recompiling

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I'm working on an Angular 4 project in Visual Studio Code.  Is there any way to stop it from endlessly recompiling? 'Ng serve' is the command I use.  Ideally, what I would like Visual Studio Code to do is to rebuild automatically when I make changes, but not to get into a cycle of constant rebuilding and rebuilding without end, even when no changes are made. In those circumstances all I can do is CTRL-C to end the loop, and enter 'Ng serve' again. Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: I'm not familiar with what you are describing. `ng serve` will watch for changes to files. It will recompile when files change.

Comment: Have you solved the problem please? If you have, how? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

When running ng serve, the compiled output is served from memory, not from disk. This means that the application being served is not located on disk in the dist folder.

You can use

```
ng serve --poll 1000
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I'll try it tomorrow and check your answer if it works.  The constant recompiling is really a nuisance!

Answer (score 3):

Setting the watch option false will stop automatic rebuilds:

```
   ng serve --watch=false
```

The full list of **ng serve** options are [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/serve), or use --help after the command.

Comment: This will cause to stop recompiling at all. The author however wants single rebuild after save.

Answer (score 1):

If you are saying that ng serve keep recompiling even though no changes have been made I did the following to resolve this issue i did the following:

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core
```

Comment: Very often, "ng update @angular/cli @angular/core" is not allowed. I tried, and I got messages saying that "Incompatible peer dependencies found."  'Package "codelyzer" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/compiler" (requires ">=2.3.1 <8.0.0 || >7.0.0-beta <8.0.0" (extended), would install "9.0.7").'

Comment: I think the issue can relate to a number of causes, this particular solution helped me out.

Answer (score 0):

I happened to come across your question and [this github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5368) at the same time. I'm not sure whether this could be part of your problem and I haven't solved my same issue, but I figured this might help in case you hadn't seen it.

Oof, broke the cardinal rule and just posted a link. Some of the suggestions listed there are:

- Check whether you have anything reading from or writing to your directory while you're serving the app (a couple of people reported backups were causing their problems)
- Don't serve in multiple browsers at the same time (I can't figure out why this might be causing the problem, but someone reported that solution worked for them)

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching for a solution to the problem for over half a year, and I've tried everything I could find on the Internet, but nothing worked. I'm using Window 10.

Finally, without any other choice, I solved the problem the following way:

```
    Remove VSCode from your computer COMPLETELY and then reinstall it.
```

If you want to keep your settings, please go to settings of your VSCode, type in settings.json, or just .json, either you copy the content and keep it, or you right click it in the EXPLORER on the left to "Reveal in File Explorer" and then copy and keep it. If you have your own "keybindings", copy and keep the file from the same folder.

To remove VSCode COMPLETELY, please follow the following steps:

```
    1. In VSCode, delete "node_modules" and "package-lock.json" first, and then, 
    2. Go to "Console Panel", go to "Programs", click "Uninstall a program", 
       and then uninstall "Visual Studio Code".  

    3. Open Run (Win + R, i.e. press the Windows Key and the R key),
    4. Enter "%appdata%",
    5. Press Enter,
    6. Delete folder "Code".
    7. In the address field on the top of your computer, go to the folder 
       with your name as the folder name, and delete folder ".vscode".
```

Alternative to steps 3-7, use the folder path:

```
    => C: drive 
    => folder "Users" 
    => folder with your name (your own folder)
    => delete folder ".vscode"
    => folder "AppData" (sometimes it's hidden) 
    => folder "Roaming"
    => delete folder "Code".
```

**After that, you can reinstall VSCode, run command "npm install", and that's it.**

Please note that I solved **MY** problem that way. Although I cannot guarantee your problems can be solved in the same way, you can try it because it starts everything from scratch.

Also don't worry about how much trouble you'd go though. It's actually very simple and almost no trouble at all.